# Is there a retro-compatiblity between two logpoints?

Tags: logging

As said in the title, we have 2 logpoints siem "searched" and "storage" both presently on version 6.2.

We want to upgrade the "searched" to v6.5. And we wonder if there will be a retro-compatibility between the two versions. Will the "searched"  be able to use logs stocked on a previous version logpoint "storage"?

Comment: What framework and programming language are you using? Please specify in the tags

Comment: hi @VadimKotov. Actually I'm using a SIEM called Logpoint. I havn't seen any tags like "SIEM" or "Logpoint" used before. And I cannot create new tags since it require a certain number of reputation.

Comment: Created [tag:logpoint] tag for you

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have already upgraded your Logpoint servers to 6.5 or above, but for future reference I can provide an answer:

As the searchhead use an API to communicate with the backend where the data itself is stored, there are usually not any big changes and it may work.
You'll need to read the changelogs provided by Logpoint with each update to find out if there are any major changes in the API.

If you on the other hand, were to import logdata (index+data) from a newer version to an old version, that may fail if the data being imported is written by a newer version of the Lucene indexer. (Logpoint 6.7.x had some changes in the indexer together with general rewrite of all internal code from Python 2.7 to 3.7)